# Global variable are not being initialized from within a listener

Tags: android, initialization, android-volley, global

I'm trying to initialize a global ArrayList from within a listener (to deal with JSONArray objects from the Volley library in different places of the code). However, when I try to access it in the Oncreate method it seems to be uninitialized.

I tried the same with different static and non-static variables i.g. int[], String, etc. but the problem seems to persist.

NOTE: 
The Question class is used for app development purposes:

```
public class Question {

private String question;
private boolean answer;



public Question(String question, boolean answer){
    this.question = question;
    this.answer = answer;
}

public String getQuestion() {
    return question;
}

public boolean isAnswer() {
    return answer;
}
```

}

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {




private String url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json";
private static  ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
int  [] intArr = new int[10];
String str = "Hello";



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    // calling the method where the variables are re-initialized
    getQuestions();

    // printing results after re-initialization
    System.out.println("Mainactivity======================");
    System.out.println("intArray: "+ intArr[0]);
    System.out.println("STR: "+ str);
    System.out.println(questionArrayList.get(0).getQuestion());





}



public void getQuestions(){

    JsonArrayRequest arrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

               // Response Listener
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {


                    // Test variables:
                    MainActivity.this.intArr[0] = 110;
                    str = "HI";



                    for(int i=0; i< response.length(); i++){
                        try {
                            // initializing ArrayList<Question>
                            questionArrayList.add(new Question(response.getJSONArray(i).getString(0), response.getJSONArray(i).getBoolean(1) ));
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }




                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

   RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
   queue.add(arrayRequest);


}
```

}

output:

I/System.out: Mainactivity======================

I/System.out: intArray: 0

STR: Hello

D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: myapp.com.triviaapp, PID: 29167
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{myapp.com.triviaapp/myapp.com.triviaapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: System.out.println(questionArrayList.get(0).getQuestion()); is causing the crash, since questionArrayList is empty since you haven't got the response from server yet.

Comment: Is there any workaround apart from doing the work inside the listener? @Carnal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The String is getting modified by the listener, however the listener is getting executing at some later point in time, after onCreate has finished. If you add a second log within the listener you will see that it gets called afterwards. This is because the listener doesn't get executed until it gets a response from the network, which will always take longer than it will take for onCreate to finish executing

Comment: Yes, I have already tested that. But is there any workaround apart from doing the work inside the listener? @chris2112

Comment: Not really. If you need to have gotten the response before the code has executed then the only way to ensure that is to not call your code until after you have gotten the response. The simplest way to do that would be to do the work in the listener. However, you may want to look into following a design pattern like MVP or MVVM as doing so will force you to separate the view logic from the business logic which will make it easier to avoid these issues

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println(questionArrayList.get(0).getQuestion());`  <- here you getting crash, because array list is empty.

You can put printing information after getting result:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // calling the method where the variables are re-initialized
    getQuestions();
}
```

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

    // Test variables:
    MainActivity.this.intArr[0] = 110;
    str = "HI";

    for(int i=0; i< response.length(); i++){
        try {
            // initializing ArrayList<Question>
            questionArrayList.add(new Question(response.getJSONArray(i).getString(0), response.getJSONArray(i).getBoolean(1) ));
        } catch (JSONException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Mainactivity======================");
    System.out.println("intArray: "+ intArr[0]);
    System.out.println("STR: "+ str);
    if (!questionArrayList.isEmpty()) { // and check if we have at least one element
        System.out.println(questionArrayList.get(0).getQuestion());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see. But the thing is that I need to work with the questionArrayList out of the getQuestions() method.